# after ubuntu-tweak, restart, the ubuntu was in tty1 login mode

Tags: restart, ubuntu-tweak

When in 12.04, if I run **Ubuntu-Tweak** -> **Janitor** tab, check all boxes click **Clean**, after re-start ... my Ubuntu will in `tty1` mode. So I run what is instructed in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and my Pangolin back normally.

But after upgrade to 14.04, yesterday I re-install Ubuntu-Tweak (in order to give it a try) and run it as before. but after restart ... I found the problem remains!

But now I really don't know what to do? Because when using *utopic*, it said `"server not found"`. By using *trusty*, it said all is `"the newest version"`

I also run: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` but nothings happen.

And I tried `sudo service lightdm restart` but the output is:

```
stop: unknown instance: stop: job failed to start
```

`Ctrl+Alt+F7` but the output is just a sparkling `_` (underscore mark)

How to make my Ubuntu back in normal GUI?